# Book where girl can travel to alternate world through colored rings

Tags: story-identification, books

Can anyone tell me the title and author of a book where a girl can see rings of differing colors and by stepping through those rings she is transported to other worlds?

Not every one can see the rings and only those who can are able to travel through them.

She is also transformed to a creature suitable to live in what ever alternate reality she travels to.

Answer (score 5):

This is *[Spaceling](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1547133.Spaceling)* by Doris Piserchia.

The blurb closely matches the description.

> ".......the ability to see the other dimensional rings that float in
>   the earths atmosphere was a late mutation of a few space-age
>   humans.Daryl was under care of the institution for muters ,and she had
>   discovered that **if you jumped through the right ring at the right time
>   it would land you in another dimensional world and another shape**...."

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, yes, "Spaceling" is indeed the book and I was able to fine a hard cover edition on the book on Amazon.com

Comment: Nice. Don't forget to mark this as "accepted"